# Symplectic reduction by angular momentum

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose I have a Hamiltonian with three first integrals $L_1,L_2,L_3$ satisfying \begin{equation}
\{ L_1, L_2 \} = L_3, \; \; \{ L_2, L_3 \} = L_1,  \; \; \{ L_3, L_1 \} = L_2,
\end{equation}
where $\{ \cdot, \cdot \}$ is the Poissonbracket. I want to find the maximal amount of degrees of freedom by which the Hamiltonian can be reduced.

Specfically I want to use a generalization on the Marsden-Weinstein-Meyer theorem as indicated by this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166534/reducing-degrees-of-freedom-with-first-integrals).

Observe that the Lie brackets induces a Lie algebra $ \simeq \mathfrak{so}(3)$.

**Problem 1:** I am not really sure how to define the momentum map $\mu: M \rightarrow  \mathfrak{so}(3)^*$. I would think that it is defined by $\mu:= (L_1,L_2,L_3)$. But I am not really sure.

Choosing values for $L_i$'s, i.e. a point $P\in\mathfrak{so}^*$, you can reduce the number of variables by $3+m$ where $m$ is the dimension of the stabilizer of $P$ under the coadjoint action.

So I need to find the coadjoint action. To do this I want to find $Ad^*$ such that $<F,Ad_X(Y)  >=<Ad^*_{X}F^*,Y  >$ where $F \in \mathfrak{so}^*$ and $X,Y \in \mathfrak{so}$ where $<\cdot , \cdot>$ is the natural pairing between  $\mathfrak{so}^*$ and $\mathfrak{so}$.

**Problem 2:** How is this natural pairing defined? Like $<L_i^*, L_j>= \delta_{ij}$ (with $\delta_{ij}$ the Kronecker delta)?

I think the coadjoint action will correspond to

\begin{equation}
Ad^*_{L_1} (L_2^*)  = L_3^*, \; \; Ad^*_{L_2} (L_3^*)  = L_1^*,  \; \; Ad^*_{L_3} (L_1^*)  = L_2^*,
\end{equation}

**Problem 3:** It is really unclear to me how to compute the stabilizer group. Do I just take a constant vector in $P \in \mathfrak{so}^*(3) $ and compute the dimension of

\begin{equation}
\{X : Ad^*_X P=P  \}?
\end{equation}

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The infinitisemal $SO(3)$-stabilizer at $p\in M$ is $\{Y\in \mathfrak{so}(3)\mid ad^*_Y(X_p)=0, X_p\in T_pM\}$. It depends on the details of the  $SO(3)$-action. There is a principal stabilizer, unique up to conjugation.